# WTForms - how to display SelectField Choice's Label without rendering the SelectField

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a situation where I would like to display form fields' 'data' only ( not rendered as the fieldtype).

This  is generally trivial by using the field's .data attribute but I cannot see how to do so for a SelectField where I want to display the label of the selection not its data.

Simple example:

```
class testform(Form)
  name = StringField()
  fruit = SelectField(choices=[('1','Lemon'),('2','Lime')])

myform = testform(name='foo', fruit='2')


#in template
{{myform.name.data}} &nbsp {{myform.fruit.data}}
```

This displays **foo 2** but I want to display **foo Lime**

There does not appear to be a way to  reference fruit.data.label

This would be easy if I was using an external Enum but in this case the  SelectField **IS** the enum so I am kinda stuck.

Any ideas how to get the label for a selection?

Answer (score 1):

You can populate your form by wrapping your class in a function w/ parameters

```
def populate_testform(name_default_value, fruit_default_value):
    class testform(Form):
        name = StringField(default=name_default_value)
        fruit = SelectField(choices=[('1','Lemon'),('2','Lime')], default=fruit_default_value)
    return testform()


myform = populate_testform('foo', '2')
```